# C Function Macro Of Node

Tags: c, dictionary, macros, struct, nodes

I am trying to make a node that can accept any key value types. So far it works when I use it once, but when I use it another time, I get errors.

Below are the codes I've written:

`map.h`:

```
#ifndef Data_Structures_map_h
#define Data_Structures_map_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define node(key_t, value_t)    \
    typedef struct node {       \
        key_t key;              \
        value_t value;          \
    } node

#endif /* Data_Structures_map_h */
```

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "map.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    node(char*, int);
    node* n = malloc(sizeof(node*));
    n->key = "first";
    n->value = 1;

    printf("the node n has a key of %s and a value of %d.\n", n->key, n->value);

    // error starts from here
    node(char, char*);
    node* n2 = malloc(sizeof(node*));
    n2->key = 'a';
    n2->value = "first";

    printf("the node n2 has a key of %c and value of %s.\n", n2->key, n2->value);

    return 0;
}
```

What should I do to make it work?

EDIT:

The error is `Redefinition of 'node'` and the rest are warnings.
I'm using Xcode.

Comment: Are you trying to implement `c++ templates` in C ?

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include a note of the exact errors you see please?  If the errors are at runtime, can you also explain what you'd expected to see happen.

Comment: Your node structs all have the same name. You'll need to decorate it somehow.

Comment: @VoidPointer I'm trying to implement a map data structure in C.

Comment: I have never seen this sort of code in C, does anyone have any teaching examples?

Comment: @simonc I get errors when building the project. I'll post the errors now

Comment: @Armin: Take look into `man queue` and the corresponding header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're redefining the `struct node` when you use the macro a second time. You need to somehow make sure that all structs have unique names. Otherwise the compiler will complain about `conflicting types` and `redefinition of structs` as [seen here](http://ideone.com/moCSr9).

**[Example](http://ideone.com/gMlWX4):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define node(name, key_t, value_t)    \
    typedef struct  {                 \
        key_t key;                    \
        value_t value;                \
    } name;                           \

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    node(stringIntNode, char*, int);
    stringIntNode* n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
    n->key = "first";
    n->value = 1;

    printf("the node n has a key of %s and a value of %d.\n", n->key, n->value);

    node(charStringNode, char, char*);
    charStringNode* n2 = malloc(sizeof(*n2));
    n2->key = 'a';
    n2->value = "first";

    printf("the node n2 has a key of %c and value of %s.\n", n2->key, n2->value);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> the node n has a key of first and a value of 1.
>
> the node n2 has a key of a and value of first.

Comment: I feel `stringIntNode* n = malloc(sizeof(*n));` is more fail-safe. 1+ anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    void *key;
    void *value;
} node;

static void *_vp;
#define box(type, value) (_vp = malloc(sizeof(type)), *(type*)_vp=value, _vp)
#define unbox(type, obj) (*(type*)obj)

int main(void) {
    node* n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->key = "first";//Reference type as it is
    n->value = box(int, 1);//Value type boxing

    //Reference type cast, Value type unboxing
    printf("the node n has a key of %s and a value of %d.\n", (char*)n->key, unbox(int, n->value));

    node* n2 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    n2->key   = box(char, 'a');
    n2->value = "first";

    printf("the node n2 has a key of %c and value of %s.\n", unbox(char, n2->key), (char*)n2->value);

    return 0;
}
```